# How to load a .js file 'locally'?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, conflict

First of all: 'Locally' neither means "localhost", nor "local folder". It means a code area or a code space or a code region.

I have two JS (`*.js`) files for my site. One is to show a news ticker and other is to load something on hover. They are conflicting, and I can't remove any one of 'em because I need 'em.

So a thing comes up to my mind is: as I can make many things locally, why not I load a js file locally? Suppose:

```
<?php 
if('condition') {
DO IT ONCE;
}
?>

<?php 
if('other_condition') {
DO STH ELSE ONCE;
}
?>
```

In such case, the first condition doesn't bother the second condition. Even though the first one is doing, the second one is also doing well. No conflict, nothing.

If I can load a JS locally for a specific purpose and then break the JS loading further, then if I load other JS, she won't find any JS before, because that's for a specific purpose for the specific region only.

I think I'm clear with my idea. I'm here with a WordPress site, loading code specifically for home page using `is_home()` function. I want such a way to load a JS file for a region, and then break it to let the other JS function properly.

Comment: Post some of the conflicting scripts.

Comment: WordPress "News-Ticker" plugin is loading `cycle.js?ver=3.4.2` in `header.php` with an `wp_enqueue_script()` function. And for another specific onhover task, I need [jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js) to be loaded. I want both works for me, but they are conflicting in my page. When the onhover works, the ticker stops.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `jQuery.noconflict()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've designed your Javascript well, you can have two scripts that don't interfere. Without seeing the actual scripts, it's hard to recommend improvement. You could introduce new scopes for each of the scripts:

#### script1.js

```
(function() {
    var script_variable = document.getElementById("my_form");
    script_variable.onchange = function() { /* ... */ };
})();
```

#### script2.js

```
(function() {
    // Same name!
    var script_variable = document.getElementById("other_element");
    script_variable.onclick = function() { /* ... */ };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Load each in a separate iframe.

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but a bit of explanation wouldn't be bad

Comment: I hope this could be a correct answer. Would you please elaborate this?